# Dense subspace of dual of reflexive Banach space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a reflexive Banach space and $Y$ be a subspace of $X^*$ with the property that for all $x\in X$ with $x\neq 0$ there exists an $f\in Y$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$. Prove that $\overline{Y} = X^*$.

**Attempt:** Basically we need to prove that if $f \in X^*$ then there exists some $y\in Y$ such that $\lVert f-y\rVert_{X^*} < \varepsilon$. To do so we write
$$\lVert f - y \rVert_{X^*} = \max_{\lVert x^{**} \rVert = 1} |x^{**}(f-y)| = \max_{\lVert x \rVert = 1}|f(x) - y(x)|$$
From there I got stuck. Note that the first equality is a result of Hahn-Banach theorem while the second comes from the fact that $X$ is reflexive. Alternatively, I thought about proving that $(\overline{Y})^\circ \neq \emptyset$ which would imply that $\overline{Y}=X^*$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If  a subsapce of  a normed linear space is not dense then there is a non-zero continuous linear functional which vanishes on the subspace. Hence if $Y$ is not dense in $X^{*}$ then there exists $F \in X^{**}\setminus \{0\}$ fuch that $F=0$ on $Y$. By reflexivity $F \in X$. Do you see a contradiction to the hypotheis now?

Comment: So I separate $\overline{Y}$ and an element of $X^* \setminus \overline{Y}$. Then there exists some $\psi \in X^{**}$ with $\psi(f) = 0$ for all $f \in Y$. Since $X$ is reflexive $\psi = \tau(x)$ for some $x \in X$ where $\tau$ is the natural embedding of $X$ to $X^{**}$. Then $\psi(f) = \tau(x)(f) = f(x) = 0$ for all $f \in Y$, a contradiction. Is this correct?

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

If $\overline Y\subsetneq X^*$, take $f\in X^*\setminus\overline Y$. By Hahn-Banach, there exists $\psi\in X^{**}$ with $\psi(f)=1$ and $\psi|_Y=0$. Since $X$ is reflexive, there exists $x\in X$ with $\psi(g)=g(x)$ for all $g\in X^*$. But then $y(x)=\psi(y)=0$ for all $y\in Y$, a contradiction.